# Maven command with shell variable not giving expected results

Tags: bash, shell, maven

This command returns the expected output.

```
mvn clean verify -Dcucumber.filter.tags="@Card"
```

But below command returns another result, it's skipping all cucumber testcases.

```
PARAMS='-Dcucumber.filter.tags="@Card"'
mvn clean verify $PARAMS
```

What would be the difference that would lead to this issue between these two commands?
And any idea to make this work by keeping cucumber params in a variable.

Comment: Could fix by using below command, but if anyone can explain what's happening, that would be great.
```bash -c "mvn clean verify $PARAMS"```

Comment: It will have different results because the double quotes are included. You ran it like `mvn clean verify '-Dcucumber.filter.tags="@Card"'`. Quotes aren't re-evaluated after parameter expansion.